# Android 3.0 not supporting form submits

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

We know that there is a bug in android 3.0 and above that it does not accept query strings.
Now as a consequence of this,I am not able to submit my search form as it always says 
 "something.html?search_input=" is an error webpage.What is the suggested work around.I even tried POST method ,but then submit event was not even firing.Please advice.

Comment: When you tried POST did you set uses-permission in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Do we even have to add permission for internal forms with in the app?if so can you tell me what permission?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using phonegap 1.0 for my app